# Openbravo: Add a field to a window

Tags: window, field, openbravo

I am trying to add a field following the HowTo in the [documentation](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_add_a_field_to_a_Window_Tab) with no errors in the process.

The problem comes when I think I am done, I visit Multiphase Project page and it does not load and shows this error:

Error occured: freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: get(tabView) failed on instance of org.openbravo.client.application.window.StandardWindowComponent

[image]

I have tried to repeat the HowTo but I couldn't find where I might be getting it wrong.

Comment: Have you done the ant export.database and smartbuild ?

Comment: This solved the problem. I was only running smartbuild. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the "Reports and Processes" window, where you created the process check whether "Manual.." is checked.. if not then check it.
2. run "ant smartbuild -Dtr=no"

Do not forget to comment whether this works or does not work...